# Evaluating $\log(\exp(x)+1)$ for negative $x$

Tags: floating-point, precision, computer-arithmetic

With double precision, I get $\log(\exp(-3)+1)=0.048587351573741958$, which already has $4$ incorrect digits, and $\log(\exp(-30)+1)=9.348... \times10^{-14}$, which only has two correct digits.

What is the most elegant way to circumvent this? I tried a Taylor series of $\log(y)$ around $y=1$, but even with 14 terms I still didn't get all digits correctly for $x=-3$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the (IEEE standard) library function `log1p`, which should be present in all programming languages. The function `log1p(x)` returns $\log(1+x)$, and is implemented with particular attention to accuracy when $x$ is small. It is designed to solve exactly this kind of problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use your own implementation to evaluate the function, take a look on [this article](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/07/25/trick-for-computing-log1x/). Otherwise, just go with log1p as suggested by @Frederico Poloni in his answer.

For more information about the log1p function read [this other article](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/07/math-library-functions-that-seem-unnecessary/) from the same author.

Comment: Second link hits the nail on the head,  much to my embarrassment I have never thought about these issues